# I have a dataframe where I want to search the column for different string contains and replace them with their respective alternate names

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a data set where I want to normalize the time column. I am performing this by using str contains. I would accomplish this by creating 3 df and find those values in each df but I want to know if there is a better way.

Input:

```
Finance_ID  Short_Name  School_Hours
29161           LASALLE         09:00 AM-04:00 PM
23531           HAMMOND         09:00 AM-04:00 PM
23031           EARLE           09:00 AM-04:00 PM
25111           REINBERG        09:00 AM-04:00 PM
23771           HERZL           09:00 AM-04:00 PM
30051           BEARD           07:30 AM - 02:30 PM
22921           AZUELA          08:00 AM - 03:00 PM
29051           ERICSON         09:00 AM-04:00 PM
30101           SALAZAR         09:00 AM-04:00 PM
22321           BRIDGE          08:00 AM-3:00 PM(PK-4),7:45 AM-2:45 PM(5-8)
26541           WOODSON         09:00 AM-04:00 PM
22931           DENEEN          09:00 AM-04:00 PM
25811           WENTWORTH       09:00 AM-04:00 PM
25361           SHIELDS         08:00 AM - 03:00 PM
29371           SABIN           09:00 AM-04:00 PM
23011           DRAKE           09:00 AM-04:00 PM

Current code:
s=df[df['School_Hours'].str.contains('7:',na=False)].replace(True,7)
e=df[df['School_Hours'].str.contains('8:',na=False)].replace(True,8)
n=df[df['School_Hours'].str.contains('9:',na=False)].replace(True,9)
```

Expected output:

```
Finance_ID  Short_Name  School_Hours
29161           LASALLE         9
23531           HAMMOND         9
23031           EARLE           9
25111           REINBERG        9
23771           HERZL           9
30051           BEARD           7
22921           AZUELA          8
29051           ERICSON         9
30101           SALAZAR         9
22321           BRIDGE          7
26541           WOODSON         9
22931           DENEEN          9
25811           WENTWORTH       9
25361           SHIELDS         8
29371           SABIN           9
23011           DRAKE           9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like

```
df['School_Hours'].replace({'7:':7,'8:':8,'9:':9},regex=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do a `split` on `-` and convert to `pd.to_datetime` then call `dt.hour`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.School_Hours.str.split('-').str[0]).dt.hour
#df['School_Hours']=pd.to_datetime(df.School_Hours.str.split('-').str[0]).dt.hour
```

---

```
0     9
1     9
2     9
3     9
4     9
5     7
6     8
7     9
8     9
9     8
10    9
11    9
12    9
13    8
14    9
15    9
```

Comment: while this would work it gives wrong hour for the school Bridge as it has 2 start times and I wnat the earliest(7:45AM). 08:00 AM-3:00 PM(PK-4),7:45 AM-2:45 PM(5-8)

Answer (score 2):

use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
m1 = df['School_Hours'].str.contains("7:")
m2 = df['School_Hours'].str.contains("8:")
m3 = df['School_Hours'].str.contains("9:")

df['School_Hours']= np.select(condlist=[m1 ,m2 , m3 ], 
                         choicelist=['7', '8','9'],
                 default=df['School_Hours'])
```